# How to integrate many-to-one field into django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have three model classes like these: `InstallationReportPartInstance` has a many-to-one relationship to `InstallationReportData`.

```
class InstallationReportData(FormData):
    installationDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Date of Installation")
    deliveryOrder = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Delivery Order")
    unitSerialNumber = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255, verbose_name="Unit S/N")
    unitHours = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, verbose_name="Unit Hours")
    visualInspection = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Visual Inspection")
...

class InstallationReportPartDefinition(models.Model):
    deviceType = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=DeviceProfile.TYPE_DEVICE, default='E', verbose_name="Device Type")
    productCode = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, verbose_name="Product Code")
    itemDescription = models.CharField(max_length=1023, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Item Description")
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Quantity")


class InstallationReportPartInstance(models.Model):
    definition = models.ForeignKey(InstallationReportPartDefinition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="instances", verbose_name="Definitions")
    installationReport = models.ForeignKey(InstallationReportData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parts", verbose_name="Installation Report")
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Received")
    installed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Installed")
```

I have a form for `InstallationReportData` that should look like this:

```
Other form fields...

| Product Code | Description | Quantity | Received | Installed |
|    xxx1      |   desc1     |  2 items |    YES   |     NO    |
|    xxx2      |   desc2     |  1 set   |    NO    |     NO    |
|    xxx3      |   desc3     |  2 items |    YES   |     NO    |
```

Or, in real:
[image]

So, the view is like this:

```
class InstallationReportView(BaseCreationView):
    model = InstallationReportData
    form_class = InstallationReportDataForm
    template_name = 'mism_web/forms/installation_report.html'
    permission_denied_message = "You do not have permission to fill installation report data."
    parts = None

    # Create and set needed parts as instance variable.
    def get_initial(self):
        super(InstallationReportView, self).get_initial()
        device_type = self.workflow.device.device_type
        if device_type is not None:
            self.parts = InstallationReportPartDefinition.objects.filter(deviceType=self.workflow.device.device_type)

    # set context for parts
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InstallationReportView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['parts'] = [InstallationReportPartInstance(definition=p, installationReport=None, received=False, installed=False) for p in self.parts]
        return context
```

Template code for parts (inside the form) looks like this:

```
    Other form fields...

    <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Received</th>
            <th>Installed</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for part in parts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ part.definition.productCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.definition.itemDescription }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.definition.quantity }}</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input id="id_part_received_{{ part.definition.pk }}" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="id_part_received_{{ part.definition.pk }}"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input id="id_part_installed_{{ part.definition.pk }}" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="id_part_installed_{{ part.definition.pk }}"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now, I don't know how to set the part instance values for the `InstallationReportData` form in `form_valid` method. Can you help me understand how to get this done? I have been stuck for a day and I can't really figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not create fields manually like that, but rather to use Django's Form fields. The relevant one here is the [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

Comment: I don't think this provides what I need.

Comment: @nakiya can you elaborate? You want a way for users to pick the corresponding model for your foreign key in a form, right?

Comment: @udadub: um, not  really, I not only ant to pick multiple corresponding models for the foreign key, I also want to edit values of those multiple models at the same time.